# Access Vertical Scrollbar focus on top of the form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

Any ideas on how to keep the scrollbar/focus on the top of a form?

I have continous form with many textboxes and listboxes that make the user scroll down the form no matter the resolution size of their screen.  Ever since I implemented a Listbox with a rowsource query that will vary on the record, every time I change records the vertical scrollbar of the form will change focus to the bottom of the form.

I tried changing focus to controls on the top of the page or changing ways to change the rowsource of said listbox (using vba code like listbox.RowSource = theSQLQUERY or making the rowsource of the listbox with the sqlQuery).  It used to work before I implemented that sourcecode, it had a sourcecode before and the problem never happened.

The rowsource query looks like this :

```
where active_flag = 0
```

My question is, How can I keep the vertical scrollbar/focus on the top of a form taking into account the listbox that changes rowsource?

Comment: Ever since I have started using that "where active_flag = 0" my scroll bar has been focusing on the bottom on the page every time the active_flag = 0 for that record.  I am baffled and I tried it all, the problem is 100% there.

Answer (score 0):

The key is:

> Ever since I implemented a Listbox with a rowsource query that will vary on the record, every time I change records the vertical scrollbar of the form will change focus to the bottom of the form.

Your code is iterating through every single record, from top to bottom. It goes to the bottom because that's where the code stops. That's fine, it's how Access works.

So, after that code, add the following:

```
Me.Recordset.MoveFirst
```

Or

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acFirst
```

Comment: It did not work, I am 100% sure the culprit is the listbox.  I have 2 subforms in my form, no bound controls and I am using a filter to get the ID of the record I am using. My guess is that maybe the subforms are getting the focus since they are in the bottom/halfway of to the bottom in the form.  Any suggestions?

Comment: OK it's hard to know what is going on exactly but if there are subforms on the form that are linked to data on the parent form, that might be causing the problem. In which case what I said won't make a difference, it's true. I'd probably break the link and update the subforms OnCurrent instead.